# how to pass information to a background process in bash

Tags: bash, process, embedded-linux

I have created a bash script and it runs in the background.  It has a PID which is stored in a file, and I can use KILL to pass predefined signals to the process.

From time to time however, I'd like to pass information to the process manually.  Preferably what I would like to happen is to be able to pass a string or array of information, which is captured through TRAP, then the forever loop inside the bash file will process the information.  Is there an easy way to pass information into a background process?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a fifo, have the main process write to it and have the child read from it.

```
mkfifo link
run_sub < link &
generate_output > link
```

Comment: Very cool feature.  Going to test it to see if it'll be suitable for my program.  I was thinking about creating a queue like data structure in bash, but it seems like someone already beat me to it.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I will remember it.That's all kinds of awesome.

Comment: @jliu83 No, that's why one (or both) of the ends has to be backgrounded. If I read your post correctly, your program reading from it is just going to loop over all the input, is there something you need it to do while waiting?

Comment: Okay solved the problem.  Parent sends a Kill -HUP signal, then send pipe to child, which traps the HUP and read from pipe.  This way the program doesn't block, and retains functionality when not reading from pipe.  Is there another way around this?  This feels hackish and a bad use of bashism.

Answer (score 1):

Have it listen on a socket and implement a protocol to achieve your communication aims, probably a bit much for bash.

Or, have it try to read a particular file on receipt of a particular signal. For example, it is common for programs to re-read their configuration files on receipt of a HUP.